# Converting From Explicit to Parametric Form

Tags: geometry

How do I convert $y=\operatorname{arctan}(x)$, when $x$ exists within $[-2.8,8]$
to parametric form of $\big(x(t),y(t)\big)$, $t$ exists within $[0,1]$?

Comment: you substitute the expression of $x(t)$ in place of $x$ and you get both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the correspondence between $t$ and $x$ linear: $x=-2.8+10.8t$. Then:

$$x(t)=-2.8+10.8t$$
$$y(t)=\arctan(-2.8+10.8t)$$